# prob with showing div in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am trying to show a specific div in a colorbox but instead whole page comes in colorbox. here is my html code

```
<div id="right">
    <div id="photo_preview">
        <a rel="example1" href="#photo_preview"><img class="photo_preview_image" src="female.png"></img></a>
        <label class="photo_preview_caption">Caption</label>
        <input class="photo_preview_caption_input" type="text" name="caption_" size="30" value=""></input>
        <input class="photo_preview_album_art" type="radio" name="album_art" title="Album Art" value=""></input>
        <img class="photo_preview_delete_image" src="Dustbin.PNG" title="Click To Delete Pic"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is colorbox function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
    $("a[rel='example1']").colorbox(

    );

    //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
    $("#click").click(function(){ 
        $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an option in colorbox like

```
$("a[rel='example1']").colorbox({inline:true});
```